# Find a differential for $-x^2\sin(t)-\sin^2(x))dt+(2x\cos(t)-t\sin(2x))dx=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

So, $P=-x^2\sin(t)-\sin^2(x), \ \ Q = 2x\cos(t)-t\sin(2x) $

$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}= -2x\sin(t)-2\sin(\cos(x))$$

$$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial t}=-2x\sin(t)-\sin(2x)$$

So, it seems that $\frac{\partial P}{\partial x} \neq \frac{\partial Q}{\partial t} $, but in the textbook there is a solution for this problem, so I assume I derived something incorrectly?

Comment: Yes, the second derivative is $2\sin x\cos x=\sin2x$.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe your change fixed the problem, so the meaning of the question changed. You should add it as a comment or answer instead.

Comment: Oops, I thought it was a typo. I can undo my change.

Comment: There is a typo in the first derivative. $$\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial x} = -2x\sin(t) - 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $$P(t,x)=-\sin^2(x)=-2x\sin(t)-2\cos(x)\sin(x)=x^2\sin(t)$$
$$Q(t,x)=2x\cos(t)-t\sin(2t)$$
then we get
$$\frac{\partial P(t,x)}{\partial x}=-2x\sin(t)-2\cos(x)\sin(x)=\frac{\partial Q(t,x)}{\partial t}$$
define $$f(t,x)$$ such that $$\frac{\partial f(t,x)}{\partial t}=P(t,x)$$ and $$\frac{\partial f(t,x)}{\partial x}=Q(t,x)$$
let $$f(t,x)=c_1$$ and integrating $$\frac{\partial f(t,x)}{\delta t}$$ with respect to $t$ to find $$f(t,x)$$

$$f(t,x)=\int-\sin^2(x)-x^2\sin(t)dt=x^2\cos(t)-t\sin^2(x)+g(x)$$

$$\frac{\partial f(t,x)}{\partial x}=2x\cos(t)-2t\cos(x)\sin(x)+\frac{dg(x)}{dt}$$

$$\frac{\partial f(t,x)}{\partial x}=Q(t,x)$$
so 
$$2x\cos(t)-2\cos(x)\sin(x)t+\frac{d g(x)}{dx}=2x\cos(t)-\sin(2x)t$$

so $$\frac {dg(x)}{dx}=0$$ and
$$f(t,x)=c_1$$
and we get

$$x^2\cos(t)-\sin^2(x)t=c_1$$

Comment: The only thing I don't get in your solution is that $f(t,x)=x^2cos(t)-tsin^2(x)+g(x)$ and you come to conclusion that $g'(x)=0$, then $g(x)$ must be some constant, but you emit it altogether and write the solution as $g(x)=0.$